# Undirected Graph Java

Tags: java, graph

I'm currently working on graphs. I have an example: you enter 8 edges (1-2,2-4,4-1,3-6,3-7,3-5,6-7,6-5). Should be printed the count of components (2) and the number of nodes the largest component have (3). I dont understand how it is 3.
I tried to draw it, I got the right amout of components - 2, but the bigger one have 4 nodes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It is important to ask questions with clear concise problem statements (there is no question in your post).

Answer (score 0):

A component is a maximal subgraph such that a path exists between each pair of nodes in this subgraph. If the graph is directed, as in your case, you can distinguish between *weak* and *strong* components. For the former, you look for paths while ignoring the link directions, whereas for the latter, you take them into account.

In your graph, the first part (1->2->4->1) is a directed cycle, so it is both a weak and a strong component. The second part (3,5,6,7) forms a weak component, but not a strong one. Indeed, one cannot go from 7 or 5 to 3 or 6 by following links using the directions. Moreover, one cannot go from 6 to 3.